# How can I reach this list in other views/pages?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to reach a list that I made in a page and when I try to find it on another page I can't seem to find it.
This is how the code looks like, and as you can see I have put it as "Public".

```
public partial class EventPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<theGuestListMembers> ourEventList = new List <theGuestListMembers>();
}
```

I for example want to use it in a void (button) on another page but cant find the list.

Comment: Make it `static` : ` public static List<theGuestListMembers>`

Comment: hm yeah ok did that now but still can't seem to find it. Do i need to put a variabel before or something in my void function to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the same list from every pages, you need to specify it as static. so your declaration will be like the following:

```
 public static List<theGuestListMembers> ourEventList = new List <theGuestListMembers>();
```

Hence you can access the same list in another pages by using:

`EventPage.ourEventList`